# One Super App or Many Single-Purpose Apps

Tags: api, mobile, application-design, applications, sdk

While Players like Rappi/Alibaba / Wechat have gone the super app way, i.e on single app to host many unrelated services, Ecosystems like Google, Amazon etc still have multiple single purpose applications e.g google suite apps like mail, calendar, hangout, meet etc.

What criteria would a product manager look at while deciding how to bundle an enterprise application.

i.e would you have a  Single Super App with many SDK's or Multiple Single-Purpose Applications linking multiple services via API's.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

For the user it is easier to have a single app for everything, as the users doesn't have to know or remember which app to use for which purpose and doesn't have to switch between apps which may slow down the workflow.

For developers, on the other hand, it is easier to have smaller apps that are focused to one central task and they can always share code in between them via libraries/modules if required, so it's also not more work for them.

As a product manager you need to make both sides happy, because you require customers to produce income, yet you require developers to even a product to sell.

However, if you look at the history, you will see that small apps have a much higher chance to survive as most big applications sooner or later vanished from the market either completely or because they were split up into smaller ones. There are only a few notable exceptions to that rule. Which implies that it is much harder to maintain a big app in the long run. So it's also a question what your long run strategy will be.

As usual, you need to find a good middle course, I guess.